# Global variable to local variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, global, local

I know global variables are created when they are declared outside a function (says [W3Schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools)).

If I create a global variable and edit it in a function, does it become local? Does the new value given by the function become the global value?

Comment: Why dont you test it ? Keep it simple silly :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, no, editing a global does not make it local:

```
var myglob = 5;
function incGlob() {
    myglob = myglob + 1;
}

incGlob();
console.log(myglob); // is 6 now
```

However, if you pass the global variable as an argument, the argument is a local copy:

```
var myglob = 5;
function incArg(myloc) {
    myloc = myloc + 1;
}

incArg(myglob);
console.log(myglob); // is still 5
```

Note that objects are passed by reference, so editing the member variables of an argument variable changes the member variables of the original object passed in:

```
var myglob = { foo:5 };
function editLoc(myloc) {
    myloc.foo = 6;
}

editLoc(myglob);
console.log(myglob.foo); // foo is 6 now
```

Finally, note that the local variable in `editLoc`, above, is just a reference.  If we try to overwrite the entire object (instead of a member variable), the function simply loses the reference to the original object:

```
var myglob = { foo:5 };
function clobberLoc(myloc) {
    myloc = { bar:7 };
}

clobberLoc(myglob);
console.log(myglob.foo); // myglob is unchanged...
// ...because clobberLoc didn't alter the object,
// it just overwrote its reference to the object stored in myglob
```

Answer (score 5):

No, editing the global variable will not change the variable's scope. The new value assigned becomes the global value.

http://jsfiddle.net/RtnaB/

```
myGlobal = 'foo'; // notice no 'var' keyword, implicitly global (DON'T DO THIS)

console.log(myGlobal); // logs 'foo'

var myFunc = function () {
    myGlobal = 'bar';
};

myFunc();

console.log(myGlobal); // logs 'bar'
```

Comment: I prefer `window.myGlobal = 'foo'` instead of `var myGlobal` because the use of `var` is misleading outside of a function... (it is *not* a lexical variable, but a property and does not work with the same closure rules)

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

You will only create a local variable if you use the `var` keyword to *declare* it inside a function.

Comment: Nope.  I just did it.  `var` does nothing.  The declared variable inside the function, will still point to the global variable.

Comment: @Bear: No; `var` does create a local scope.  Show me a demo.

Answer (score 2):

The new value becomes the global value.