# Making a local copy of a global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887291/js-global-variable-to-local-variable), if I pass a global variable as an argument to a function, that global becomes a local copy.

If that is the case, why does [this jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4o0mwnb/) behave the way it does? Shouldn't the alert show `dog, cat` and not just `cat`?

I even went one further step than the example and specifically copied the global variable into a local variable, but the result is the same. I'd really like to be able to `shift()` the local while keeping the global intact.

Comment: Arrays and Objects are exceptions. They share same reference. You need to learn about those :)

Comment: It doesn’t make a copy. It’s an assignment like any other variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5314911/707111. You can copy arrays using `.slice()`.

Comment: Dupe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104494/does-javascript-pass-by-reference

Comment: primitives are passed by value, object are passed by reference

Comment: Not by reference, by value, containing a reference

Comment: By passing in the `animals` global var to your function, you mutated the global not the local.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JavaScript only has pass-by-value. I just wanted to make it clear from the beginning.

To keep things simple, the code below illustrates the difference between *pass-by-value* and *pass-by-reference*.

#### Pass-by-value

```
function change (x) { x = 7; }

var x = 1;
change(x);
console.log(x); // 1
```

#### Pass-by-reference (not available in JavaScript)

```
function change (x) { x = 7; }

var x = 1;
change(x);
console.log(x); // 7
```

Now, you need to understand that some types are allocated on the heap, while others are allocated on the stack. So what does that mean?

Well, let's suppose you have a variable.

```
var x = 5;
```

Here the value *lives* on the stack. Which means, if I do

```
var y = x;
```

I will have two variables on the stack, both with their own copy of `5`. Simple types are always allocated on the stack.

Objects, on the other hand, *live* on the heap. When I do,

```
var o1 = {x: 5};
```

the object will be allocated on the heap, but the value within `o1` variable, which is a reference to the object in the heap (let's call `#ref1` the value within `o1` variable), will be allocated on the stack. Which means, if I do

```
var o2 = o1;
```

I will have two variables on the stack, both with their own copy of `#ref1`, but *only* one object allocated on the heap.

Now, you can use the reference to access object's members, and because both `o1` and `o2` contain a reference to the same object, they will be able to *locate* the object in the heap an change it's `x` value.
If, however, I do the following

```
o2 = {x: 7};
```

this will change the value stored on the stack for the variable `o2` (will call the new value `#ref2`). Now, there are two objects on the heap and two references stored on the stack.

Finally, let's talk about your problem:

```
// The array (which is an object) is allocated on the heap
// {animals} variable will contain a reference to that object (#ref1)
var animals = ["dog", "cat"];

// Pass-by-value
pushSearchList(animals);

// Local variable {passedAnimals} will contain a copy of #ref1,
// but both {passedAnimals} and {animals} can modify the same object
function pushSearchList(passedAnimals){
   var localAnimals = passedAnimals;
   localAnimals.shift();
   alert(animals);
}
```

Now, what if you want your own copy of the array object? Just clone the array using:

```
// {arr} will receive reference to a new array allocated on the heap (#ref2)
var arr = passedAnimals.slice(0);
```

Comment: Thank you. Slice() was indeed the solution and the explanation was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Considering this code:

```
var animals = ["dog", "cat"];

pushSearchList(animals);

function pushSearchList(passedAnimals){
    var localAnimals = passedAnimals;
    localAnimals.shift();
    alert(animals);
}
```

`animals` is NOT copied to the function. It is passed by reference.  Anything you do to the `passedAnimals` ARRAY will affect `animals` as well.  If you SET the variale `passedAnimals` to something else, like a copy of itself (ie. `passedAnimals.slice()`), then changes to the new array will no longer affect the source. Because array objects can be changed, they are mutable (liable to change).

In contrast, strings on the other hand (though they can look like an array of characters) are immutable (cannot change). If you pass them to a parameter, a copy will be made.

More on passing by value or reference: http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: JS only has pass-by-value

Comment: Not sure what you mean. In fact, JS passed things using handles in the backend, usually as references (like in C#).  When all references are gone, the GC collects the space.  I should know - I created V8.Net. ;)

Comment: Pass by reference is often taken to mean the equivalent of `ref` in C#, for example. JavaScript passes references, but by value. Without talking about implementation details, you can even say everything is passed in the same way – even if primitives are implemented as references (and strings are; copying them would be wasteful), their immutability means you can’t ever tell the difference.

Comment: True, but in C#, how many times is `ref` used? Rarely ever in my years of development.  To me, reference means just that, to objects, not variables passed using `ref`.